# How to get from Bodrum to Datça when ferry isn't running?

Tags: transportation, ferries, turkey, bodrum

I'd like to go to Datça when visiting Turkey in early October. It looks like normally there is a 2-hour ferry ride from Bodrum (an easy transit transfer city) to Datça during the summer tourist season. But according to the [Bodrum Ferry's website](http://www.bodrumferryboat.com/en/calendar.asp), it looks like those ferries do not run past the end of August.

Is there a way to get from Bodrum to Datça in October that is as quick, easy, and cheap as taking the ferry? I do not plan to have a car, so I would prefer public transport or private bus - something that I can just buy tickets for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To travel between Bodrum and Datça by bus, you will need to transfer in Marmaris.

If you can't find direct service between Bodrum and Marmaris, you can always transfer in Muğla, which is the provincial capital and a stopping point for long-distance buses travelling from north western Turkey to the western Mediterranean. If you can find an intercity bus for either leg of this trip, it will be more comfortable, but you will likely find it easier to take one of the local companies' smaller buses since they will have more departures. Bodrum to Marmaris will probably take close to four hours thanks in part to the steep descent prior to the plain near Gökova, but it really depends on how lucky you are with a connection in Muğla.

From Marmaris, there will be frequent minibuses to Datça.

According to the ferry website, the cost for a one-way ticket is €12. The total bus fares will exceed that, but not by a huge amount.

Comment: Could you add any extra information? How long it takes, maybe a bus company name? Cost perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

Indeed! What SigueSigueBen said.

If you cant find a direct bus to Marmaris then just go for Mugla. From Mugla you will find a bus to Marmaris all day long. When you are inMmarmaris there will be minibuses to Datca. But I think the ferry will be available in September too. If the weather isn't bad they will be available.

When you arrive in Datca, be sure you visit Orcey hotel or even accommodate there. It has a fantastic architecture and a blue flagged beach.

Have fun on your trip!

Comment: You mention that the ferry will probably be available in September, but I'm going in October - is there any way to confirm whether the ferries will run then? If I take a bus from Marmaris or Mugla, is it necessary to book in advance at that time of year?